# How to Filter record using mysql Php

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with mysql and Php,and i am getting data in following format

```
Array
(
    [country] => India
    [total] => 23
)
Array
(
    [country] => USA
    [total] => 1
)
Array
(
    [country] => Japan
    [total] => 1
)
```

I just want that if total match of any countries then should get in same array like following format

```
Array
(
    [country] => India
    [total] => 23
)
Array
(
    [country] => USA,Japan
    [total] => 1
)
```

Here is my mysql query

```
SELECT country,COUNT(*) as total FROM doctors GROUP BY country ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Here is my code

```
<?php foreach ($data as $total) { 
echo "<pre>";print_R($total);
?>
<p><?php echo $total['country']; ?><?php echo $total['total']; ?></p>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: What's the problem with iterating over array and collect countries with same `total`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$countriesByTotal = [];

foreach ($data as $row) {
    $countriesByTotal[$row['total']][] = $row['country'];
}

foreach ($countriesByTotal as $total => $countries) {
    $countriesByTotal[$total] = [
        'country' => implode($countries, ','),
        'total'   => $total
    ];
}

$countriesByTotal = array_values($countriesByTotal); // optional

print_r($countriesByTotal);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [total] => 23
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [country] => USA,Japan
            [total] => 1
        )
)
```

[rextester-demo](https://rextester.com/EXP69974)

Another way is just to change your SQL query using `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT total, GROUP_CONCAT(country) as country
FROM (SELECT country,COUNT(*) as total FROM doctors GROUP BY country) sub
GROUP BY total
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

`array_walk()` can be used to concat the country of the same total count.

```
$data = [];
array_walk($array, function ($value) use (&$data) {
    $data[$value['total']] = isset($data[$value['total']])
        ? ['country' => "{$data[$value['total']]['country']},{$value['country']}", 'total' => $value['total']]
        : $value;
});

print '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```